# x axis on top of the figure in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [change position of tick marks of a single graph, using ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766422/change-position-of-tick-marks-of-a-single-graph-using-ggplot2)

How can I get the x-axis on top of my plot using ggplot2/R?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639973/how-to-plot-with-x-axis-at-the-top-of-the-figure) is similar, but in python.

Comment: I believe that's still on the [todo](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/619) list.

Comment: Is there any reason you could not use lattice plotting methods?

Comment: @DWin could be a matter of aesthetics.

Comment: U can try to make an annotate layer http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/
otherwise u definetly will find it in the documentation