# Put x-axis at the top of a Bokeh figure

Tags: python, bokeh

Is it possible to put the x-axis at the top of a Bokeh plot?  If so, how?

This is similar to [this question on matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639973/how-to-plot-with-x-axis-at-the-top-of-the-figure)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pass `x_axis_location="above"` to `bokeh.plotting.figure`