# How can I show the upper and right axes in a bokeh plot?

Tags: bokeh, axes

I would like to always show the upper x-axis and right y-axis in my bokeh plots.

Is there a command to simply add these axes to the diagram?

Comment: Please [read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) how to ask question. Narrow down your error, and provide [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Put x-axis at the top of a Bokeh figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107360/put-x-axis-at-the-top-of-a-bokeh-figure)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how to show top and right axis line, simply add *outline_line_color='black'* inside bokeh's plot.figure().